# Can a static class have a property of type of a static class?

Tags: c#, static

I am trying to group app settings in groups for more clarity. For this is created a static AppSettings.cs class that should contain the different settings groups of the parts of my application:

```
AppSettings
  |--AppSettingsGroupA
  |--AppSettingsGroupB
  |--AppSettingsGroupC
```

The code looks like:

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public static AppSettingsGroupA GroupASettings{ get; set; }
    public static AppSettingsGroupB GroupBSettings{ get; set; }
}

public static class AppSettingsGroupA 
{
    public static IPAddress IpAddress
    {
        get{return IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1"]);}
    }
}

public static class AppSettingsGroupB 
{
    public static IPAddress IpAddress
    {
        get{return IPAddress.Parse("192.200.2.100"]);}
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get a error saying that the static types can not be used as return types.

Can this be fixed or do I need to use some other technic to be able to call my settings in different groups like: AppSettings.AppSettingsGroupA.IpAddress or AppSettings.AppSettingsGroupB.IpAddress

Thanks for you help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is kind a awkward what you are trying to archive here, I do not see real need why both `AppSettingsGroupA` and `AppSettingsGroupB` have to be `static`. What you want to archive could be done just by removing `static` from `AppSettingsGroupA` and `AppSettingsGroupB`... That way you could still have `static` properties within `AppSettings`.

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    AppSettings.GroupASettings = new AppSettingsGroupA();
    AppSettings.GroupBSettings = new AppSettingsGroupB();

    Console.WriteLine(AppSettings.GroupASettings.IpAddress);
    Console.WriteLine(AppSettings.GroupBSettings.IpAddress);
}

public class AppSettingsGroupA 
{
    public IPAddress IpAddress => IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1");
}

public class AppSettingsGroupB 
{
    public IPAddress IpAddress => IPAddress.Parse("192.200.2.100");
}
```

---

n.b. c# 6.0 property syntax has been used

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!!

Comment: @Ephie since you are new contributor the actual way to say tnx is to upvote the helpful answers.

Comment: @Ephie https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 2):

"No", basically - you can't do that. If you just want them hierarchical, you could **nest** the static types inside `AppSettings`, but IMO the more usual thing would be for them to just *not be static*.

Nested static version:

```cs
public static class AppSettings
{
    public static class GroupASettings
    {
        public static IPAddress IpAddress { ... }

    public static class GroupBSettings
    {
        public static IPAddress IpAddress { ... }
    }
}
```